# Fire an event when user move to next input field or release input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This code is in foreach loop of php

```
$('input[name="<?=$value?>"]').on('change',function(){
        spanval = $(".formscore").text();
        width = $(".formProgressbar").width() / $('.formProgressbar').parent().width() * 100;
        width = Math.round(width);
        var currentval = $(this).val();
        if(currentval != ''){
          $(".formscore").text(parseInt(spanval) + <?=$sql123->score?> + '%' )
          $(".formProgressbar").width(parseInt(width) +  <?=$sql123->score?> + '%' )
        }else{
          $(".formscore").text(parseInt(spanval) - <?=$sql123->score?> + '%' )
          $(".formProgressbar").width(parseInt(width) -  <?=$sql123->score?> + '%' )
        }
      });
```

this code changes progress-bar as input field changes.

now the problem is that *It changes every time when field is changed*.

I tried Following Handler of jquery

1. change
2. blur
3. keyup
4. keydown
5. focusout/in

**I want** to Fire an event when user move to next input field or release input field. I am open to any other suggestions.

Comment: You go with jquery **onblur** event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to add event listener to dynamically generated element, instead of

```
$('input').on(event, function(e){
  // won't work for dynamically generated element
});
```

you should use next code:

```
$('form').on(event, 'input', function(e){
  // will work for dynamically generated element
});
```

This code is for next html:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="">
</form>
```

Where `input` is dynamically generated element, `event` is your event (`change`, `blur`, etc.)

Comment: This is not relevant to my question. but call as suggestion.

Comment: @MadCoder, you can try to use `'input[name="<?=$value?>"]'` as a selector in `$('form').on(event, 'input[name="<?=$value?>']', function(e){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="<?=$value?>"]').on('blur',function(e){
  //Do something
});
```

Comment: Still it incress value if value is already filled and i change it.

Comment: remove change handler

Comment: I Copy your code Still it incress if value is already filled  and i changes it.

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the question with some explanation of how and why this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a class to your input when the user triggers the blur event. Then use this class to block the next trigger of the event.

(You can also use jQuery's [.data () method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of a class)

Or better, use an each loop triggered by the blur event to count all inputs filled to increase or decrease the progress bar.

See [JS fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/b0Lfkt1n/1/)

```
var total = $('input').length
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  var counter = 0;
  $('input').each(function() {
    if($(this).val()) {
    counter += 1;
    }

  })
  console.log('Progress : '+counter+'/'+total+'. Percent : ' + (counter*100/total)+ '%')
})
```

Comment: Comment edited, js fiddle link added : https://jsfiddle.net/b0Lfkt1n/1/